# Yod coalescence across words - only with "you(r(s))"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, vowels, consonants

I'm asking specifically about Yod* coalescence when connecting two words together.

Some very (neat) phenomenon in American English is to "fuse" `you/r/s` when the word ends in `t`/`d`/`z`:

**I was thinking about you**  -> `aɪ wəz θɪŋkɪŋ əˈbaʊtʃu`
**what did you do?** -> `wʌt| dɪʤu du?`
**close your eyes**  -> `kloʊʒəɹ aɪz`

From my observation, Americans only coalesce some or non of the t+y, d+y and z+y combination, depending on their regional accent and how articulate they want to sound (the more they coalesce, the informal it sounds).

Another observation I have is that *across words* (I'm not talking about inter word combinations like future, solider and vision), it can only happen when the second word is you/your/yours.

Am I correct? are there any other words which start with **y** and can be coalesced? or the only "valid" coalescence is when the second word is you/r/s?

I mean, one can't say "but yeah, you're right" as something like "bucheah, you're right" without sounding very awkward.

If anyone wants to answer about different dialect of English (British, Australian,etc.) they are welcome, but the question is about American English, with bias toward Midwestern/West coast/General American accent.

*hey, that's a Hebrew letter!

Comment: Good question! If you include _y’all_ and similar variations that are based on _you_, then I think you’re right. I can’t seem to naturally produce yod coalescence with any other word either. With the _you_-based words, I have more or less free variation when it comes to /-t j-/ between coalescing to /-tʃ-/ and reducing the /t/, leaving /-ʔ j-/ (or in some cases deleting the /t/ entirely). With other words, only the latter is possible. And producing something like [hiwəˈʒεɫɪ̵nəʔmi] (with [ʒ]) for “He was yelling at me” feels unnatural, too.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet another question I had - what about words which has /yu/ at the beginning, but they are not "you"? would you pronounce "but using it is wrong" as "bu-chu-zin it is wrong"? or you would just glottolize the T instead?

Comment: Definitely glottalise. [bəˈtʃuːzɪ̵nɪtsɹɑːŋ] with [tʃ] would represent “But choosing it is wrong” if I were to produce it. “He was using it” _can_ just about come out as [hiwəˈʒuːzɪ̵nɪʔ], though. Feels less unnatural with _using_ than with _yelling_.

Comment: So, quit strangely this is a phonological phenomenon which is affected also by the *meaning* and not entirely by sounds alone, like the other phonological phenomena. thanks you!

Comment: "Yod-coalescence" seems a peculiarly Jewish term; most linguists, absent a religious context, would call the phenomenon "palatalization" and would proceed to describe instances of it in almost every language.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm not so sure. I've seen many articles and academic works referring to it as "Yod coalescence", including Wikipedia. as for Judaism, the religion itself doesn't care much about phonology :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet sans any other answer, if you post you comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @DavidHaim: Re: "this is a phonological phenomenon which is affected also by the *meaning* and not entirely by sounds alone": If it's restricted to a certain set of words, or a word and its derivatives, then I think it's probably better considered a lexical property, rather than being affected by meaning as such.

Comment: This type of word coalescing depends heavily on whether a syllable is stressed or not. "What did you DO?" becomes "What [dɪʤu] DO?" or even "What [dɪʤə] DO?" However, "I did the right thing, but what did YOU do?" or "If you didn't do x, what DID you do?" stays as [dɪd ju]. Same with "but yeah": "But YEAH, you're RIGHT" never becomes [bətʃə]. However, "But yeah RIGHT, like he would ever do that" does become [bətʃə]. Same with any other combo of this sort--when it comes to slurring words together, it happens when those syllables are unstressed.

Comment: So to add to my previous comment, it's not so much that this type of coalescing can't happen to any other word except "you", it's just very rare to have two naturally unstressed syllables occur across words, other than with short, low-content words like "you" or "yeah", which people can afford to de-stress to the point of slurring without impacting their understandability. This is also how "what do you WANT" becomes "wache WANT" and "What do you DO" becomes "wajye DO".

Comment: @filistinist what a great answer! why didn't you post it as an answer? I would have accepted it.

Comment: @DavidHaim I think my comment is a very partial answer at best. However, you might be right--posting it might be a good idea. It might generate more traffic and hopefully some more answers. I will try to do some more research before I post it, though. I might be able to dig up a more nuanced explanation. But I will post soon, and will delete my comment when I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This coalescence is not so special. It actually seems to be natural and normal at times.
"And now, **about yesterday**" could be heard as

> and now, **a bough chesterday** (or, **jesterday**)

and the person so speaking not be aware that he never really eaid "yesterday".
It may be that Americans perform this coalescence more than some other English speakers, but it is surely not a new phenomenon.

The Classical Latin word for "yoke" might be used as an example.
**IUGUM** [majstro.com](http://www.majstro.com/dictionaries/English-Latin/yoke) in Latin gives a number words in modern languages (the **I** is equivalent to the English"y").

In Italian [wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/enit/yoke) we have **giogo** which sounds much like "jogo" in English spelling.
In English we have "jugular" [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yoke) and "subjugate" from the Latin **SUB IUGEM** , among others.

Spanish retains  the "y" sound: **yugo**, but French does not: **joug**. Neither does Portuguese: **jogo**. Perhaps there was a shift in Vulgar Latin that did not occur in Castilian Spanish. May be there are other explanations.

As to American English, this coalescence might just be normal to the language, and not exceptional. I am an American English speaker. If I say **SUB IUGUM** as a Latin phrase, formally, the "y" sound will be intact. If I informally say the phrase it might sound like

> sabjugem

and I will have committed the coalescence, and not given it a thought.

The pity is we have only recently been able to go beyond good guesses as to how sounds change in language over time. The "y" sound in **yesterday** may not have been there 1500 years ago. German uses a "hard G" in its current word (**gestern**) [Collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-german/yesterday) and some, or all Anglo-Saxon dialects may have had the hard sound instead of "y". It is possible that "y" is not stable in all dialects of English today. I fear it will take thousands of hours of sound recordings to sort this out. This is a very good question.

Comment: We have some spelling-based evidence that even in Anglo-Saxon times, words like "yesterday" were pronounced with the /j/ sound rather than /g/, as in German. Words like "year", that don't have a /g/ sound in German, were spelled with the letter "g" in Ango-Saxon. This suggests that already at this time, the /j/ sound that Anglo-Saxon inherited from Proto-Germanic had merged with the palatalized sound from Proto-Germanic *g, and both could be spelled as "g".

Comment: @ sumelic I agree  basically. But all of the figuring of sounds 2000 years ago have to be just "good guesses".. Dutch today uses neither a "y" or "g""  but  a hard "h" in our "yesterday". "y" may well have superseded   /g/ by 1500 years ago in all English dialects, but,I do not think I will say it for sure.  Thank you for the comment.